# Where to store a Python module in a Snakemake workflow

Tags: snakemake

The Snakemake documentation has a nice recommendation for a repository structure to use when you are wanting to distribute or reuse a workflow in another setting. It is described here https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html and looks like so:

```
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── LICENSE.md
├── workflow
│   ├── rules
|   │   ├── module1.smk
|   │   └── module2.smk
│   ├── envs
|   │   ├── tool1.yaml
|   │   └── tool2.yaml
│   ├── scripts
|   │   ├── script1.py
|   │   └── script2.R
│   ├── notebooks
|   │   ├── notebook1.py.ipynb
|   │   └── notebook2.r.ipynb
│   ├── report
|   │   ├── plot1.rst
|   │   └── plot2.rst
|   └── Snakefile
├── config
│   ├── config.yaml
│   └── some-sheet.tsv
├── results
└── resources
```

In my particular application I have packaged all of my Python code into a Python module called "KAPy" - this module contains a set of helper functions for both defining the workflow and running the code. Is there a best practice for where to place such a module in a workflow? Remember that I also want to be able to import it into the Snakemake, preferably via

```
import KAPy
```

Hope that someone has some good ideas along these lines.